# How to control loop based on input? (Why does this loop forever?)

Tags: loops, cobol

I'm new to COBOL and just wondering about some weird things I have going on. I want to make a loop that goes through and executes 3 paragraphs until the input provided by the user in the first paragraph is "no".

Is there any way I can use this input or do I have to change everything around so that the input is given before the first paragraph is executed? Right now my loop looks like:

```
PERFORM PARAGRAPH1 WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL INPUT = "no"
     PERFORM PARAGRAPH2
     PERFORM PARAGRAPH3
END-PERFORM.
```

Currently it just keeps looping and never ends, which as you can guess is a problem. I think I may just not fully understand the scope of COBOL yet, this is my first actual attempt at COBOL.

Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: I dont know ANY COBOL but "AFTER UNTIL" seems really fishy...

Comment: from what I've been reading, TEST AFTER followed by an UNTIL makes it like a do-while loop on languages like Java and C++

Comment: It says WITH TEST AFTER and UNTIL INPUT = "no" meaning it will perform the test after each loop and that the condition is INPUT = "no". I presume that `INPUT` is working storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting little program you have there. As I see it there are a few
problems.

The `PERFORM` verb comes in a few different flavours (basic, TIMES, UNTIL and VARYING).
The `PERFORM UNTIIL` flavour, the one you are trying to use, has the following
'railroad track' syntax:

```
  __________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
 |                                                                                                  |
 | >>__PERFORM__ _procedure-name-1__ _______________________________ __| phrase 1 |_ ____________>< |
 |              |                   |_ _THROUGH_ __procedure-name-2_|               |               |
 |              |                     |_THRU____|                                   |               |
 |              |_| phrase 1 |__ ________________________ __  END-PERFORM___________|               |
 |                              |_imperative-statement-1_|                                          |
 |                                                                                                  |
 | phrase 1:                                                                                        |
 | |__ ____________________________ __UNTIL__condition-1__________________________________________| |
 |    |_ ______ __TEST__ _BEFORE_ _|                                                                |
 |      |_WITH_|        |_AFTER__|                                                                  |
 |                                                                                                  |
 |__________________________________________________________________________________________________|
```

Note that just after the `PERFORM` verb you can code either `procedure-name-1` or `phrase-1` followed
by an arbitrary number of `imperative-statement-1`. These are mutually exclusive options (ie. there is no
path in the diagram allowing you to 'loop back'. Once you pass through one of these options the other
is no longer available. However,
your code is doing both! I would not have expected this to compile due to the ambiguity inherent
in the code (I tried compiling your program and thankfully my compiler issues an error).

The other problem I see is the use of `INPUT` as a variable name. `INPUT` is one of a large
set of COBOL reserved words
so cannot be used this way (again I would expect the compiler to issue an error). The simple fix is to
add something to the name (eg. WS-) to disambiguate it.

As Joe pointed out, the typical COBOL way to do what I think you are attempting is:

```
    PERFORM PARAGRAPH1
    PERFORM UNTIL FUNCTION LOWER-CASE (WS-INPUT) = 'no'
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH2
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH3
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH1
    END-PERFORM
```

I assume `PARAGRAPH1` is responsible for setting the loop control variable `WS-INPUT`.

Or (assuming `PARAGRAPH2` and `PARAGRAPH3` do not reference `WS-INPUT` and they are executed
at least once)

```
    PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL FUNCTION LOWER-CASE (WS-INPUT) = 'no'
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH2
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH3
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH1
    END-PERFORM
```

The basic difference is that the first example is a typical DO-WHILE construct (test before
entering loop body) and the second is a typical DO-UNTIL construct (always execute 1 pass
through the loop body and test before subsequent passes).

A third way, outdated method, would be:

```
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH1
       PERFORM PARAGRAPHS UNTIL LOWER-CASE (WS-INPUT) = 'no'

 PARAGRAPHS.
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH2
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH3
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH1
       .
```

This is equivalent to the first example above. 
I do not recommend this coding style - it dates back to the way things were done 30
or more years ago.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful. My Computer Science keeps telling me learning COBOL is pointless, but I'm having some fun with it!

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the inline perform with the paragraph perform.  Very odd.  I suspect it only compiled because you mixed Cobol-74 terminators (the period) with Cobol-85 terminators (End-Perform).  If your compiler supports the End-* scope terminators, you should never use a period except as the end of a paragraph or you can create some very twisted and confusing execution paths.

You also need to manage case folding on your input.

The "with test after is a special beast.  It is the equivalent of a do/while in other languages.  But it can always be written with a priming read and putting the test first.

Try something like this:

```
Perform Paragraph1
Perform until function lower-case(INPUT) = "no"
    Perform Paragraph2
    Perform Paragraph3
    Perform Paragraph1
End-Perform
```

Comment: thank you!!! I gave the check to Neal because he went a little more in depth, but I appreciate you explaining the problems with the terminators to me!